# rewriterule dynamic with sub

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't fix this issue. I'm trying to get rewrite rules to work with dynamic urls like:

http://example.com/[CATEGORY]/[PAGE]/[OPTIONS]

or

http://example.com/[PAGE]

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/]) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])\/^(.*[^/])

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])\/^(.*[^/]) /index.php?url=$1/$2 [QSA,L]
```

The first rewriterule is working, but the second isn't. Also is this not clean.

Anyone who knows this?